# Usar "Declare" dentro de procedimiento almacenado en MySQL

Tags: mysql

Estuve realizando un código para que la numeración del código varchar avance de uno en uno, ejemplo

AU-0000001

AU-0000002

AU-0000003

AU-0000004

Utilizando "set" antes de ingresar al procedimiento funciona correctamente el código pero al momento de ingresarlo a un procedimiento almacenado no se puede crear.

El mensaje de error es el siguiente:

> create PROCEDURE usp_CrearAutor (
>       nombreAutor varchar(10) ) BEGIN DECLARE cadena varchar(10) MySQL ha dicho: Documentación
>
> ## 1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca '' en la linea 6

```
create PROCEDURE usp_CrearAutor
(
    nombreAutor varchar(10)
)
BEGIN
DECLARE cadena varchar(10);
DECLARE codigo varchar(3);
DECLARE numero int;
DECLARE relleno int;
set cadena = 'AU-0000001';
set codigo = (SELECT substring(cadena, 1, 3));
set numero = CAST((SELECT substring(cadena, 4)) AS INT);
set relleno = LENGTH((SELECT substring(cadena, 4))) - LENGTH(numero);
set cadena = (SELECT CONCAT(codigo,(SELECT REPEAT(0,relleno)),numero));
INSERT INTO autor VALUES(cadena,nombreAutor);
END
```

Comment: A mí no me da ningún error de sintaxis, lo único que no cuenta y asigna siempre la misma cadena. ¿Por qué no usas un id autoincremental y evitas complicaciones?

Comment: Gracias por el consejo. Sin embargo, lo que deseo saber es porque no me corre el código ya que realicé uno similar en SQL Server donde funciona sin problemas.

Comment: A mí me lo crea sin problema, ¿has probado con el DELIMITER?

Comment: Si, con DELIMITER si funciona. Lo extraño es que en ocaciones con DELIMITER también me mandaba error, comenzaré a revisar mi código para ver problemas de sintaxis.
Soy nuevo y realmente te agradezco por responder de manera rápida

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resultó que era un mal uso de "DELIMITER", finalmente mi código funciona, gracias a los que respondieron. Les comparto el código:

```
DELIMITER //
create PROCEDURE usp_CrearAutor(in nombreAutor varchar(50))
BEGIN
DECLARE registros int;
DECLARE cadena varchar(10);
DECLARE codigo varchar(3);
DECLARE numero int;
DECLARE relleno int;

set registros = cast((SELECT COUNT(*) from autor) as int);

IF registros = 0 THEN
    set cadena = 'AU-0000001';
else
    set cadena = (SELECT id_autor from autor order by id_Autor desc limit 1);
    set codigo = (SELECT substring(cadena, 1, 3));
    set numero = CAST((SELECT substring(cadena, 4)) AS INT) + 1;
    set relleno = LENGTH((SELECT substring(cadena, 4))) - LENGTH(numero);
    set cadena = (SELECT CONCAT(codigo,(SELECT REPEAT(0,relleno)),numero));
end if;
INSERT INTO autor VALUES(cadena,nombreAutor);
END//
DELIMITER ;
```